# tailwind css breakpoint not working, the content is not shifting to flex start when i hit the md breakpoint

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<div class="mt-10 flex flex-col items-center md:flex md:flex-col md:items-start bg-red-300">
        <h2 class="text-2xl text-[#4c4c4c] font-semibold">HOD'S CORNER</h2>
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1664361480105-33afc4559c40? 
                  auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&w=500&ixlib=rb- 
                  4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3BsYXNofGVufDB8fDB8fHww" 
        class="" alt="">
        <h3>Prof. Sanjay H Upadhyay</h3>
        <h4>Head, Centre for Space Science and Technology</h4>
    </div>
```

I am making a image card which should stay in center on small screen and move to flex start on large screen but the md breakpoint is not working

Answer (score -1):

If the breakpoint is not working as expected, there could be a few reasons for this:

**Configuration Issue:**
Make sure you have configured Tailwind CSS correctly in your project. Ensure that your tailwind.config.js is properly set up with the desired breakpoints. Here's an example of how you might set breakpoints in your configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'sm': '640px', // Small screens
        'md': '768px', // Medium screens
        'lg': '1024px', // Large screens
        'xl': '1280px', // Extra-large screens
      },
    },
  },
  // Other Tailwind CSS settings
}
```

**Responsive Class Usage:**
Ensure that the breakpoint classes (md:flex and md:items-start) are being applied to the correct element. In your code, you've applied these classes to the parent , which should work. Make sure you haven't accidentally overridden these classes at a smaller breakpoint.

**Order of Classes:**
Class order in the HTML can affect the rendering. Classes are processed from left to right. In your case, the md:flex and md:items-start classes should be effective when the screen width reaches the "md" breakpoint (768px by default in the Tailwind CSS configuration). If you have conflicting classes, the last one applied will take precedence.

**Clear Cache:**
If you've recently made changes to your Tailwind CSS configuration, you may need to clear your project's cache or rebuild the CSS to see the changes.

**Browser Caching:**
Sometimes, issues can be related to browser caching. Try clearing your browser cache or testing in an incognito/private browsing window to ensure you're seeing the latest styles.

Comment: Seems AI generated.